# Sufficient condition for the integrability of a stopping time $\tau$

Tags: probability-theory, lp-spaces, stopping-times

Let's consider a Brownian Motion $B$ defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$; take $\mu>0$ and define the supermartingale $X_t:=B_t-\mu t$.

Pick $a,b>0$ and define the stopping time $\tau:=\inf\{s>0\;:\;X_s\notin]-a,b[\}$.

My book says that in order to prove that $\tau\in L^1(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ it's sufficient to prove that
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}P(\tau>t)\,dt<+\infty
$$
but I can't understand why.

Comment: Because for any nonnegative random variable $Z$, whether integrable or not, $$Z=\int_0^\infty\mathbf 1_{Z>t}\,dt$$ hence $$E(Z)=E\left(\int_0^\infty\mathbf 1_{Z>t}\,dt\right)=\int_0^\infty P(Z>t)\,dt$$ as has been explained tons of times on the site.